# Android AWS: Alternative ways to post things to endpoints

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I'm new to AWS, I'm looking for an alternative recommended way instead of using Volley to post something to an aws endpoint. The current code, I'm trying to post a comment:

```
    public void submitComment(final Comments comment,
                          final RequestListener submissionListener) throws JSONException {
    String url  = this.baseURLPath + "topics/topicId/comments";
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.serializeNulls();
    Gson googleGSON = gsonBuilder.create();
    googleGSON.toJson(comment);
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(googleGSON.toJson(comment));
    JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    submissionListener.onSuccess();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("submitComment", "(onErrorResponse) ERROR HAPPENED: " +  error.toString());
                    submissionListener.onFailure();
                }
            }) {

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("Authorization", userPreferences.getToken(context));

            //params.put("Accept-Language", "fr");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(obreq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing holding you back from using [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). It works with `Gson` which you are already using and is very easy to use once you have set it up. You can also handle token based authentication with it.

For example [this article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html) will give you a great overview of Retrofit and will teach you how to use it.